# Print prime numbers from 1 to 1000 with a separator

Tags: sql-server

My query is giving correct values but I'm not able to concatenate them with a separator "&".

Desired O/p:

```
2&3&5&7&11&13&17&19&23.... so on till 997
```

My query:

```
    declare @max INT = 1000

    ;WITH all_numbers(n) AS
    (
        SELECT 2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT n+1 FROM all_numbers WHERE n < @max
    )
    select string_agg(cast(all1.n as varchar),'&')
    from all_numbers all1
    where not exists (select 1 from all_numbers all2 where all2.n < all1.n AND all1.n % all2.n = 0)
    order by all1.n
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Without using `string_agg` function it is working fine but not giving desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `ORDER BY` and use `WITHIN GROUP` to solve the:

> Column "all_numbers.n" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

error in your current statement:

```
DECLARE @max INT = 1000

;WITH all_numbers(n) AS (
   SELECT 2
   UNION ALL
   SELECT n+1 
   FROM all_numbers 
   WHERE n < @max
)
SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(all1.n as varchar), '&') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY all1.n)
FROM all_numbers all1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 
   FROM all_numbers all2 
   WHERE all2.n < all1.n AND all1.n % all2.n = 0
)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Earlier version of `SQL 2017` won't support `STRING_AGG` To Combine Column Data we can use `STUFF`. Following Code will give your desired Output.

```
declare @max INT = 1000

;WITH all_numbers(n) AS
(
    SELECT 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1 FROM all_numbers WHERE n < @max
)
select all1.n into #tbl
from all_numbers all1
where not exists (select 1 from all_numbers all2 where all2.n < all1.n AND all1.n % all2.n = 0)
order by all1.n
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
select Replace((
select STUFF((
select ','+cast(r.n as Varchar(120))
from #tbl as r
for xml path('')),1,1,'')),',','&') as dd
drop table #tbl
```

Can't Combine `RECURSION` values so Inserted all data into `#tbl` while Concatinate `&` usning `XML STUFF` Resulting as `&amp;` to avoid that first while combining used ',' then Replaced with `&`

Answer (score -1):

Just remove your order by line, else is fine.